# Динамическое добавление полей формы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

На странице insert.php есть форма, в ней есть INPUT, где надо написать вопрос poll(голосование), при клике на button надо в эту форму добавлять еще INPUTы, где надо написать варианты вопроса, динамически добавленные INPUTы должны быть таким

> `<input name = "otveti[]">`

В итоге нужный нам массив будет таким.

> `$_POST['otveti']`

```
insert.php

<?php 

?>

<form action="poll.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="vopros">
    <br>
    <button id="dobavit">Ok</button>
    <br>
    <button>Save</button>

</form>


<?php 

 $data = $_POST['otveti'];


?>
```

Нужно чтобы вопросы написанные в поле вопроса,и ответы написанные в динамически добавленных INPUT-ах,при клике на  button Save,пошли в сервер,с соответствующим id вопроса.

Comment: и в чем собственно проблема ваша заключается? как повесить js-обработчик на кнопку добавления, или как динамически создать инпут? зы: 2 поля по всегда можно показывать сразу.

Comment: Нужно чтобы вопросы написанные в поле вопроса,и ответы написанные в динамически добавленных INPUT-ах,при клике на  button Save,пошли в сервер,с соответствующим id вопроса.

Comment: то что нужно и так понятно, я спросил в чем проблема в реализации у вас.

Comment: просто нет так хорошо знаю как нужно делать

Answer (score 1):

```
var $btn = $('#dobavit');
$btn.click(function() {
    $('form').append('<input type="text" name="otveti[]" />');
});
```

Как вариант! только у button укажите тип button. Иначе при клике может происходить отправка данных на сервер.